# Rails array index changing after delete_at

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

There are three categories

```
categories = ["Category test 1 2", "Category test 1 3", "Category test 1 4"]
```

When I delete `Category test 1 2`, the array becomes `["Category test 1 3", "Category test 1 4"]` and at this time value of `i` is `0` but in next iteration value of `i` is `1` and the value at index position is `Category test 1 4` so it is not taking value `Category test 1 3` due to which hidden categories of `Category test 1 3` is not displaying.

I used method `categories.delete_at(i)`

I want that in next iteration , it should take value `Category test 1 3` not `Category test 1 4`.

Answer (score 1):

You can put logic here eg.

```
temp1, temp2 = [1,2,3,4,5,5,6,7], []
temp3 = temp1.clone
4.times { |h| temp2 = temp1.clone; temp2.delete_at(h); temp3.delete((temp1 - temp2)[0]) }
temp1 = temp3.clone
=> [5, 5, 6, 7]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set `i = 0` just before `categories.delete_at(i)` if every time you want to delete the first category

```
i = 0
categories.delete_at(i)
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

As I understood you wanted to delete all elements of Array one by one then you can use **[Array#delete_if](http://apidock.com/ruby/Array/delete_if)**

```
categories.delete_if{|a| p a}
"Category test 1 2"
"Category test 1 3"
"Category test 1 4"
 => []
```

If your concern is to delete `"Category test 1 3"` after `"Category test 1 2"` only and last element `"Category test 1 4"` should remain as it is..

```
> categories.each{|a| p categories.delete_at(0)}
"Category test 1 2"
"Category test 1 3"
 => ["Category test 1 4"]
```

---

Let me explain you your issue. You may be doing something like this:

```
categories.each_with_index do |e,i|
  categories.delete_at(i)
end
```

In first time loop index will be `0` so it delete first element `"Category 1 2"` from the `categories` and it remain something like:

```
["Category test 1 3", "Category test 1 4"]
```

Now in second loop index will be `1` and in remaining Array elements at index `1` , `"Category test 1 4"` is stated. so it delete this element instead `"Category test 1 3"` which is stated on `0` index now..

I hope it helps you. If you have any further query then feel free to comment.

Comment: Yes.. you understood it correct. Thanks.  But then how to change the index so that it will pick "Category test 1 3" not  "Category test 1 4" . I can not use delete_at(0)  as i have to delete the element at i position based on some condition.

Comment: You can use `categories.delete_at(0)` so all time index `0` (first element from remaining array) will be deleted

Comment: e holds element "Category test 1 4" but i want e should hold element "Category test 1 3" as I want to do some operations on "Category test 1 3" .

Comment: @Deepika : It will be more clear if you update your expected output after `delete_at` operation. Bcz the way you did before it holds "Category test 1 3" only.. So I am little bit confused what you exactly wanted.. which elements should be deleted and which should be remain at the end. Thanks